# Determining Patterns Across Lists

Tags: data-mining, sequential-pattern-mining

Given several lists:

| List 1 | List 2 | List 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shirt | Delivery | Outcome |
| Ladder | Outcome | Football |
| Football | Football | Teacher |
| Teacher | Teacher | Operation |
| Airport | Apple | Engineering |

I am looking to:

1. Detect that Football, Teacher, and Outcome are in several lists
2. Detect the Football/Teacher and the Outcome/Football/Teacher patterns
3. Assign a numerical value to the frequency of the patterns across the lists (ie. Football/Teacher (3), Outcome/Football/Teacher (2))

Are there any algorithms that I should be looking at in order to do any/all of these steps?  I've discovered apiori which is definitely in the right direction, but it doesn't seem to take the order of items into account.

Appreciate anyone who can point me in the right direction.